# Uniqueness of Probability Extension

Tags: probability, probability-theory

**Source**: Billingsley's "Probability and Measure" Exercise 3.13

**Question**: Show that it is impossible in Theorem 3.3 to drop the assumption that $\mathcal{P}$ is a $\pi$-system.

**Theorem 3.3**: Suppose that $P_1$ and $P_2$ are probability measures on $\sigma(\mathcal{P})$, where $\mathcal{P}$ is a $\pi$-system. If $P_1$ and $P_2$ agree on $\mathcal{P}$, then they agree on $\sigma(\mathcal{P})$.

**My Work/Question**: Let $\mathcal{L}=\{A\in\sigma(\mathcal{P}):P_1(A)=P_2(A)\}$ be the $\lambda$-system containing $\mathcal{P}$. If $\mathcal{P}$ is not a $\pi$-system, then there exists a pair of sets $A,B\in\mathcal{P}$ such that $A\cap B\notin\mathcal{P}$. Now we somehow deduce that $A\cap B\notin\mathcal{L}$ (this is where I don't know how to continue). But since $A\cap B\in\sigma(\mathcal{P})$, we see $P_1(A\cap B)\neq P_2(A\cap B)$. My problem is the "impossible" bit - why $A\cap B$ is necessarily not in $\mathcal{L}$ - could $\mathcal{L}$ not be $\sigma(\mathcal{P})$ and so the two measures would agree?

Comment: we can give an arbitrary value to $A \cap B$, so we can define infinitely many different measures that extend a measure in $\mathcal{P}$, however if $\mathcal{P}$ is a $\pi$-system then the extension to $\sigma (\mathcal{P})$ is unique